# IOS Sqlite3 Passing Opened database to a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Using php for an example:

> $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', '123456', 'xxx');

Just define $conn once, I can pass $conn to all other methods, so that i don't need to repeat the connection again when I run another query, and it's a lot faster.

```
function example($conn) {
   // do some db stuff here
}
```

Can I do the same thing in IOS sqlite3? Many thanks for helping.

```
- (void) syncScale {

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ALDI.db"]];



    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSString *postSetting ;
    postSetting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"scaleData={\"scaleDB\":["];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)

    {
        NSString *querySQL =  @"SELECT * From Table1";
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                // do something here
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }   else {
            NSLog(@"Steps Data not found");
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);

    }
}
```

Comment: Of course. Just add the parameter to the needed methods.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, I'm confusing, which parameter I should add to the method?

Comment: -(void)test:(sqlite3*)contactDB {   }, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do, is that keep the opening of database in separate block/function with a boolean return  ,rather finalize and rest the sqlite statement; Since the opening of database is made of almost static contents, the function doesn't need any parameters